# AWS S3 website versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, aws-sdk

I am running a website on AWS S3 bucket. I have to update the website once in a while. At the moment, when I do the deployment I just copy the built files to my bucket and override existing ones.

**Is there a way to do some versioning on these deployments?** I know there is a built-in versioning S3, but it is only for individual files I think.

The best option would be that every deployment is tagged with git commit-id and I could rollback to a particular commit-id if needed.

Any ideas? Already tried to name directories with commit-id -prefix, but the problem is that index.html has to live in root dir.

Comment: Your deployment versioning is in Git, not S3. S3 doesn't know what a "deployment" is, it just knows about the versions of each individual file. To rollback a deployment you would checkout a previous commit from Git, and then deploy that to S3.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know that. That is why I am looking for a solution to version entities of files such as directories in this case. I must offer a simple solution for non-technical users who could rollback the previous version just by doing some clicking action in AWS console.

Comment: So you know that S3 doesn't offer versioning like this, and Git is the best solution, but you want a different solution anyway? You mention directory versioning, but S3 doesn't even support directories. You mention non-technical users doing something via the AWS console, which sounds like the worst idea ever. Non-technical users have no business logging into the AWS console at all. If you want something non-technical users can use to rollback versions you need to build something, or setup a third-party automated deployment tool, that is aware of both Git and your S3 deployment.

Comment: Ask this question differently: Can I do blue/green style deployments with S3 static web sites? The answer is- I feel like you should, but I can't figure out a way so far! Using versioning would be a great way -- your entry point is index.html, by default S3 versioning applies a url parameter on each versioned file (index.html?versionId=1, index.html?versionId=2 etc). If you could set the S3 bucket's entry point to Index.html?versionId=1 and use that as a live-version marker, you'd have what you're looking for. But that doesn't work- access denied for some reason. Still investigating.

Comment: Some other considerations- 1) using a different index.html as the entry point, that points to a build-specific sub-folder for all file dependencies. i.e. if your build is "ac8jf0j9921" then your entry point is ac8jf0j9921.html pointing to the folder "ac8jf0j9921". 2) using route 53 to point to a different s3 bucket, but i think the a-record in r53 needs to have the same name as the s3 bucket name..

Comment: For #1 you could use CodePipeline/CodeBuild etc to automate all of this. Take the git commit hash, copy the files to a "working directory" s3 bucket, name the file appropriately/etc, copy to target s3 bucket, set the s3 entry point to the new entry index.

Comment: did you find out something @ikenator?

Comment: @ferr - to answer your modified question: you can't. It's simply, technically impossible, because, like you said, you can't "set the entry point" (there's no such concept), thus the operation would involve overwriting *at least* one file (the entry point); but S3's eventual consistency model would make it impossible to guarantee that the overwritten entry-point would consistently send all users to the new "environment". If you can relax your requirements, then it may be possible. Eg, other than the entry point, add hashes to all file names (still eventual consistency on entry point though!)

Comment: @BrunoReis i found that CloudFront could be used to essentially perform blue/green switching between different sources (e.g. versioned S3 buckets in this case). Route53 would always point to the CloudFront endpoint, while the CF resource could switch between buckets at will.

Comment: @ferr - that won't solve the problem either: you'll still have eventual consistency in the very least in the entry point, since CF itself will introduce eventual consistency (ie, the old index file will be cached in lots of POPs, and even though you can issue a request for CF to invalidate it, it's not "synchronous", so there's still a window of eventual consistency in which one request may get the old version, then another the new version, then another the old version etc).

Comment: (and just to be clear, I don't mean to imply that any of those solutions cannot ever be used as part of a blue/green deployment, it's just that if strong consistency for the deployment is a requirement, then it won't work; but if that requirement is relaxed, then your solution with CF, or even without it, would be fine)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some solution for non-technical users who could rollback the previous version just by doing some clicking action in AWS console you can try to change Index document config.

For example, you have structure in bucket like this:

- bucket/v1/index.html
- bucket/v2/index.html
- ...
- bucket/vN/index.html

It means, that you could only change the config in Bucket properties -> Static website hosting -> Index document -> from v2/index.html to v1/index.html.

Sounds like "just doing some clicking action in AWS console"

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, when using v1/index.html as the Index Document, I have this error: The IndexDocument Suffix is not well formed

Comment: You can use Page Redirect S3 feature to do this: You set the redirect by adding the x-amz-website-redirect-location property to the object metadata. The website then interprets the object as 301 redirect. To redirect a request to another object, you set the redirect location to the key of the target object. Documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS CodePipeline, and use git reverts to manage rollbacks. See [this github repository](https://github.com/elementryx/codepipeline-powered-static-website) for a cloudformation stack to set up a website on s3/cloudfront with something like this in place.

Answer (score -3):

You can configure bucket versioning using any of the following methods:

- Configure versioning using the Amazon S3 console.
- Configure versioning programmatically using the AWS SDKs

Both the console and the SDKs call the REST API Amazon S3 provides to manage versioning.

**Note**

If you need to, you can also make the Amazon S3 REST API calls directly from your code. However, this can be cumbersome because it requires you to write code to authenticate your requests.

Each bucket you create has a versioning subresource (see [Bucket Configuration Options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#bucket-config-options-intro)) associated with it. By default, your bucket is unversioned, and accordingly the versioning subresource stores empty versioning configuration.

```
<VersioningConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"> 
</VersioningConfiguration>
```

To enable versioning, you send a request to Amazon S3 with a versioning configuration that includes a status.

```
<VersioningConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"> 
  <Status>Enabled</Status> 
</VersioningConfiguration>
```

To suspend versioning, you set the status value to Suspended.

More information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already know about the versioning that AWS offers. My question was more related to versioning of single deployments as a whole. I'd like to see versions of deployments with commit-ids that I could rollback my website to a certain point if needed. I think that the versioning you were telling was about independent files..?

Comment: I have seen people make a folder for a version and then say if they use something like CloudFront just points to the folder ex. v1